# File-size differences before and after upload PHP-CURL to Windows WCF

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, file-upload, filesize

I am trying to upload a file using PHP. Not that tuff right? Well, i need to do it through Webservices WCF. Now i'm stuck with that last part. When i upload the file it is: 892599 (this is what Windows and Linux tells me on the filesystem. And also what PHP tells me. But, when it arrives on the scene (Windows Server, WCF) it's only 891400.

This must has something todo with encoding or OS differences but i have no idea where to look now. Below is my PHP code.

As you can see in the code, i tried different ways but all with the same outcome. Filesize differences. The source file (the file i try to upload is an text/plain us_ascii encoded file)

```
try{
    header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8", true);

    $filename = "ahstray.obj";
    $file_content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $file_hash = hash_file('sha512', $filename, false);
    $bits = pack("H*", $file_hash);
    $file_hash = base64_encode($bits);        
    $filesize = strlen($file_content); //filesize($filename); //strlen(file_get_contents($filename));

    $boundary = "uuid:".uniqid();        
    $headers = array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="'.$boundary.'";start-info="text/xml"',
        'SOAPAction: "'.$action.'"',
        'Host: www.url.com',
        'Content-length: '.$filesize,
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'User-Agent: PHP-Post-FileUpload'
    );
    $post_data = "\r\n\r\n\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $post_data .= "Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>\r\n";
    $post_data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $post_data .= 'Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"';
    $post_data .= "\r\n\r\n";

    $post_data .= '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
        $post_data .= '<s:Header>';
            $post_data .= '<h:FileHash xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$file_hash.'</h:FileHash>';
            $post_data .= '<h:FileName xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$filename.'</h:FileName>';
            $post_data .= '<h:FileSize xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$filesize.'</h:FileSize>';
            $post_data .= '<h:UserDomain xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$domain.'</h:UserDomain>';
            $post_data .= '<h:UserName xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$gebruiker.'</h:UserName>';
            $post_data .= '<h:UserPassword xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$encrypted_password.'</h:UserPassword>';
        $post_data .= '</s:Header>';
        $post_data .= '<s:Body>';
            $post_data .= '<UploadFileDTO xmlns="http://www.url.com/eRP">';
                    $post_data .= '<FileStream>';
                        $post_data .= '<xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/635551016730489495" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" />';
                    $post_data .= '</FileStream>';
            $post_data .= '</UploadFileDTO>';
        $post_data .= '</s:Body>';
    $post_data .= '</s:Envelope>';

    $post_data .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $post_data .= "Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/635551016730489495>\r\n";
    $post_data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";
    $post_data .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

    $post_data .= $file_content.$file_content;        
    $post_data .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";


    $sock = fsockopen("ssl://www.url.com", 443, $errorno, $error, 30) or die($error);
    $data = "POST https://www.url.com/FilesTransfer.svc HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $data .= implode("\r\n", $headers);
    $data .= $post_data;

    if($sock){                        
        fwrite($sock, $data);
        echo fread($sock, strlen($data));
        fflush($sock);
        fclose($sock);
    }        

    /*
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);

        print_r_pre($response);
        print_r_pre($error);
        curl_close($ch);
        */

} catch (Exception $e){
    print('<pre>');
    print_r($e);
    print('</pre>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this problem is just to easy. It's a **multi**part request, which means when you set then 'Content-length' you should calculate the full size of the request. So, the XML part and the size of the file you try to upload.

The request will now look like this:

```
try{

        $file_content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
        $hash = hash('sha512', $file_content, false);
        $bits = pack("H*", $hash);
        $file_hash = base64_encode($bits);       
        $filesize = filesize($filename); //filesize($filename); //strlen(file_get_contents($filename));

        $boundary = "uuid:".uniqid();     

         $xml_request = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
            $xml_request .= '<s:Header>';
                $xml_request .= '<h:FileHash xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$file_hash.'</h:FileHash>';
                $xml_request .= '<h:FileName xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$filename.'</h:FileName>';
                $xml_request .= '<h:FileSize xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$filesize.'</h:FileSize>';
                $xml_request .= '<h:UserDomain xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$this->domain.'</h:UserDomain>';
                $xml_request .= '<h:UserName xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$this->gebruiker.'</h:UserName>';
                $xml_request .= '<h:UserPassword xmlns:h="http://www.materialise.be/eRP">'.$this->encrypted_password.'</h:UserPassword>';
            $xml_request .= '</s:Header>';
            $xml_request .= '<s:Body>';
                $xml_request .= '<UploadFileDTO xmlns="http://www.url.com/eRP">';
                        $xml_request .= '<FileStream>';
                            $xml_request .= '<xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/635551016730489495" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" />';
                        $xml_request .= '</FileStream>';
                $xml_request .= '</UploadFileDTO>';
            $xml_request .= '</s:Body>';
        $xml_request .= '</s:Envelope>';

        $headers = array(
            'MIME-Version: 1.0',
            'Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="'.$boundary.'";start-info="text/xml"',
            'SOAPAction: "http://www.url.com/UploadFile"',
            'Host: www.url.com',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
            'Connection: Keep-Alive'
        );

        $post_data = "--{$boundary}\r\n";
        $post_data .= "Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>\r\n";
        $post_data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
        $post_data .= 'Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"';
        $post_data .= "\r\n\r\n";

        $post_data .= $xml_request;

        $post_data .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
        $post_data .= "Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/635551016730489495>\r\n";
        $post_data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";
        $post_data .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

        $headers[] = "Content-length: ".($filesize+strlen($post_data));

        $post_data .= $file_content;       
        $post_data .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";

        $ch = curl_init($this->wsdl_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
```